# How do I can fix the error Use no-check-certificate

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get access to the dataset using:

```
!wget https://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/easc-corpus/EASC/EASC.zip
```

But I got the following error message

```
ERROR: cannot verify liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net's certificate, issued by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
  Issued certificate has expired.
To connect to liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: The site should update their certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net` does not have a valid https certificate and wget is refusing to connect

If you are sure you want to connect to it anyway then provide the `--no-check-certificate` flag to wget to make it skip certificate validation.

```bash
!wget --no-check-certificate https://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/easc-corpus/EASC/EASC.zip
```

Comment: Ah, I see the root cause. Thank you so much!! I tried the solution and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to solve this error globally.

`echo "check-certificate = off" >> ~/.wgetrc`